# Creating rotated local grid/fishnet in QGIS with known AMG origin & rotation angle?

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, vector-grid, australia

I have a local grid with known origin that is in AMG (metres) and a rotation angle.

How do I establish that grid so that it can be projected into known CRS eg GDA94/ MGA Zone projection?

I located an plugin called ARKgrid that seemed like it would do the job, but it does not run in QGIS3 maderia.

Any suggestions ?

Am new to QGIS and at this stage a basic user.

Comment: AMG is based on AGD66 or AGD84 which needs a translation grid as the shift is not uniform, it's roughly 200m to MGA. There is a NTv2 translation which may be available from Geoscience Australia or ISCM. If you have access to ArcGis or know somebody who does the AGD66 to GDA94 NTv2 is available in the project tool.